# Using Fulltext Index Relevance turning up as 0

Tags: mysql

I have a similar query that I use across several different tables, however on this table, for some reason All of my results are coming in with a Relevance of 0.. Could anyone provide some insite to why this might be happening?

Cheers

```
SELECT  City,
MATCH (
    Street, City, State, Zipcode
)
AGAINST (
    'San|Diego'
) AS Relevance FROM address_list
WHERE 1 
AND MATCH (
    Street, City, State, Zipcode
)
AGAINST (
    '+San|Diego'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
```

My full index is on: Street, City, State, Zipcode
DB: MyISAM

Works on every other table except this one..

```
Select * from address_list where City='San Diego'
```

produces my list fine, so i'm really stuck.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same MATCH() in the select clause that you use in the where clause:

```
SELECT  City,
MATCH (
    Street, City, State, Zipcode
)
AGAINST (
    '+San|Diego'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
) AS Relevance FROM address_list
WHERE 1 
AND MATCH (
    Street, City, State, Zipcode
)
AGAINST (
    '+San|Diego'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

ft_min_word_len may be the problem. The default is 4, so the word "san" won't be included in the index.

Here's how to check it:

```
show variables like 'ft_min_word_len';
```

Comment: yes I checked this.  Thank you though, it's currently set at 2